# Excel Find alphanumeric string from text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a column containing multiple string values, like a sentence.

in that sentence i want to find one or all alphanumeric values of 10 or more characters containing atleast one `-` , and put the resulting values in another column.

For example:
the column containing sentence is like:

```
upgrade 15.07.2010, old No: WI82-01062. User moved to No: WI12-01012 02.04.2012 to a 2 user network.
```

or

```
Upgrade from lite 7/6/07, old No: PTX7-89C367EC5052-01211
```

Ideally I want a column with values like `WI82-01062, WI12-01012` for the first example, and `PTX7-89C367EC5052-01211` for the second example.

May be searching for the `-` in the string and finding the first occurrence of `blank space` at both ends would help, but I do not have any clue how to write that in excel term.

Thanks

Comment: In your three examples, the (first) hyphen is the fifth character in the string. Is this always the case?

Comment: unfortunately, no. It can be fourth, fifth or sixth character in the string.

Comment: Not got time to do the code, but try coding this up following this logic: 1. split the string and put each word into an array. 2: check array for words where len<10 and delete 3: Loop through that array and pass words that still exist to a final array, but only if they contain a "-". That array should then contain the ones you want. Just a few for each loops, arrays and redims should do it. You could  combine the steps along the way, but that is the logic you want to be following. If no-one has answered properly later then will see about an example myself

Comment: Is it at least the case that any hyphens in a given string are always part of a desired extraction? Or can there be other, non-relevant hyphens present in the string, e.g. Upgrade from lite 7/6/07 - old No: PTX7-89C367EC5052-01211

Comment: @XOR LX, I have some 26K data in the excel. I have not searched for any such non-relevant hyphens, but it can be safely said the chances of it occurring is very less. I can live with some error which can be fixed manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a regex like this (there may be better patterns!):

```
Function ExtractData(r As Variant) As String
    Static oRE                      As Object
    Dim sTemp                       As String
    Dim n                           As Long
    Dim matches
    If oRE Is Nothing Then
        Set oRE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        With oRE
            .Pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9\-]{10,}"
            .Global = True
        End With
    End If
    Set matches = oRE.Execute(r)
    If matches.Count > 0 Then
        For n = 1 To matches.Count
            sTemp = sTemp & ", " & matches(n - 1)
        Next n
        ExtractData = Mid$(sTemp, 3)
    End If
End Function
```